# Success and error run at the same time instead of displaying the error message and keeping the fields populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

When there is an error with the user input, the form fields should retain their values until the user enters the required fields. Instead, the error message is displayed and the form field is cleared anyway. How do I get it to keep the information? Here is the piece of code:

```
        }).success(clearAddStaticPageForm())
        .error(function (data, status) {
            $('#validationErrors').empty();
            // #2 - Go through each of the fieldErrors and display the associated error
            // message in the validationErrors div
            $.each(data.responseJSON.fieldErrors, function (index, validationError) {
            var errorDiv = $('#validationErrors');
            errorDiv.append(validationError.message).append($('<br>'));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `}).success(clearAddStaticPageForm())`

with `}).success(clearAddStaticPageForm)`

The parenthesis were actually executing the function instead of passing it as a callback (even when the `success` method is not called). Here is what I mean, try both of these snippets:

**With parenthesis (wrongly executes the success callback)**

```js
$.ajax({url: 'url_that_does_not_exist'})
 .success(mySuccessCallback())
 .error(function(){ alert('There was an error!'); });

function mySuccessCallback() {
    alert('The success callback was executed.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Without parenthesis (does what it is supposed to do)**

```js
$.ajax({url: 'url_that_does_not_exist'})
 .success(mySuccessCallback)
 .error(function(){ alert('There was an error!'); });

function mySuccessCallback() {
    alert('The success callback was executed.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This solves my problem, but now it's not clearing the form when the input is correct. Should I split **clearAddStaticPageForm()** out so that it looks like the error function?

Comment: @WagnerColodette No, you don't have to do that, it's perfect like this. But according to the name of that function, it looks like it clears the form (is that right?). And you added it as a `success` callback, so... it's executed when the input is correct.

Comment: Now that I've removed the parentheses I'm getting the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldErrors' of undefined.** The user is notified of the unfilled input, and when input is filled the JavaScript gives me that error.

Comment: @WagnerColodette That is because the `data` you receive is either not JSON, or does not have a `responseJSON` property. Open your JS console (F12) and go to the Network tab. Submit your form, and see what gets returned by clicking on the request in that tab, and then on "Response". If it does not look like `{"responseJSON": {...}}`, then it's not going to work.